# How to impute values for a specific condition?

Tags: r

My question may be two-fold: I would like to, for a particular condition and for a particular group, impute two sets of values.

Let me explain with data:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(rep("a",6),rep("b",6),rep("c",7)), 
                 num = c(rep(1:6, 2),rep(1:7)), 
                 status = c(rep("good",6),rep("bad",6),rep("bad",7)), value = c(100))

> df
   id num status value
1   a 1   good   100
2   a 2   good   100
3   a 3   good   100
4   a 4   good   100
5   a 5   good   100
6   a 6   good   100
7   b 1    bad   100
8   b 2    bad   100
9   b 3    bad   100
10  b 4    bad   100
11  b 5    bad   100
12  b 6    bad   100
13  c 1    bad   100
14  c 2    bad   100
15  c 3    bad   100
16  c 4    bad   100
17  c 5    bad   100
18  c 6    bad   100
19  c 7    bad   100
>
```

If the status = `bad` then build out `num` to 50 and impute `0` in the value.

So for `id` 'b' and 'c', I'd produce 44 and 43 additional rows, numbered sequentially in `num`, respectively. And the `value` for those new rows would be `0`...

Any and all help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could generate your "built out" data and then stack it:

```
require(data.table)
DT0 <- data.table(df)

DT <- rbind(
  DT0,
  DT0[status=="bad",list(num=.N:49+1L,status="bad",value=0),by=id]
)[order(id,num)]
```

You'll have to install the `data.table` package first.